# Why Am I Not Able To Embed My Custom Framework?

Tags: ios, xcode9

I have a very simple framework project, MyFramework, that builds successfully. The framework defines a single, global function, myFunction.
The framework also defines 2 global variables: MyFrameworkVersionNumber and MyFrameworkVersionString (These 2 variables were created for me by Xcode)

I have a very simple application project, MyApplication. I am adding the framework to the application project by dragging and dropping the framework package (i.e. the MyFramework.framework in DerivedData that was produced by building the framework) onto the Xcode Navigator and then selecting the framework in the Embedded Binaries section of the project's General tab.

If I add code to MyApplication that references the variable MyFrameworkVersionNumber then I am able to successfully build and run MyApplication.

If I add code to MyApplication that references the function myFunction then I am not able to build MyApplication.

---

**First Update**

---

I suddenly remembered that Carthage does exactly what I am trying to do. So, I used Carthage to build MyFramework and Voila! - I can drag/drop the Carthage build of the framework into the application project and successfully use it. So now my inquiry has become: What does Carthage know that I do not?

Answer (score 0):

Oh for heaven's sake! It turned out to be so simple. MyFramework was being built for a Generic iOS Device (arm64 architecture). MyApplication was being built for a simulator (x86_64 architecture). As soon as I matched those two up all was well. The reason that the Carthage build worked so well is that it produces a universal binary (i.e. one that contains both architectures).

I still do not understand why the MyFrameworkVersionNumber global variable was able to be accessed regardless of the architecture. But I am okay with deferring that little mystery as some arcane bit of information that will be revealed in the goodness of time (perhaps something such as that it is in a header that is structured the same for both architectures).