# Can iOS Frameworks Be Shared Without Sharing the Source Code?

Tags: ios, xcode

When Xcode is used to build an iOS framework, the end result is a package on the disk similar to the following:

[image]

Is it possible for me to give that package to another developer and have him/her include it in their own Xcode projects?

[I am having trouble doing that. Hence [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657238/why-am-i-not-able-to-embed-my-custom-framework) question. The lack of an answer lead me to distill it to its essence and post a new, simpler question.]

Comment: In general, the answer should be, "Yes, you can do that."  However, your other question's error message seems to point at Swift's "module" concept, which I don't truly understand.  Perhaps some investigation into modules, such as how they are created and located, would help.

Comment: Thanks, Phillip. That sounds promising. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer to my question is a definite **Yes**. I now know this because Carthage can do it. Upon remembering that Carthage does exactly what I am trying to do, I used Carthage to build my framework and Voila! - I can drag/drop the Carthage build of my framework into an Xcode project and successfully use it. So now my inquiry has become: What does Carthage know that I do not?

---

**Update**

---

Mystery solved! The framework and application architectures were mismatched. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657238/why-am-i-not-able-to-embed-my-custom-framework) for a bit more info.